# mongodb group one _id different key names / $dateToString two data fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My mongo collection has documents with the key `tracking.timestamp` and other documents with `tracking.soi_timestamp`. Is there a way to use both keys to `$group` in one *_id* as a new `combined_timestampfield` field?

```
_id: {
 "date": {
   "$dateToString": {
        "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
        "date": "$tracking.combined_timestampfield"
  }
}
```

**Update sample documents:**

```
{
  "tracking": {
    "timestamp": {
      "$date": "2020-06-02T05:33:10.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

...

```
{
  "tracking": {
    "soi_timestamp": {
      "$date": "2020-06-02T14:23:00.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

**desired output:**

```
{
  "_id": {
    "date": "2020-06-02"
  },
  "total": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to pick either `soi_timestamp` and `timestamp` into a common name field using [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator, lets say `actualTimeStamp` at the document level.

Then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the documents by this new projected/added field:

Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "actualTimeStamp": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$tracking.soi_timestamp",
          "$tracking.timestamp"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "date": {
          $dateToString: {
            format: "%Y-%m-%d",
            date: "$actualTimeStamp"
          }
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "date": "2020-06-02"
    },
    "count": 2
  }
]
```

[Play Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ch93vX2CPg0)

Comment: Oh, i wasn't aware of  $ifNull. Thanks for your help!